# Read RGBA Image OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, uiimageview, imagemagick, computer-vision

I am stuck with reading, processing and displaying sample.png image which
contains RGB and an additional Alpha layer.
I have manually removed background in this image and only foreground appears in
windows image slideshow propgram. I couldnt find any useful information
anywhr... when i read it from opencv usng functions imread or cvloadimage it
creates a white background by itself... i have read documentation of highgui
which states that these functions only deal wth RGB not RGBA...any help or idea
will be helpful...

Thanks
Saleh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK only current solution is to load alpha channel as separate image and then join it together. You can use [cvtColor()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) to add alpha channel to Mat with image and e.g. [mixChannels()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mixchannels) to mix it together with loaded aplha image.

Comment: thanks but how can i display it...imshow and cvLoadImage will take it as an RGB???

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there is a way to display RGBA image in OpenCV... besides, you can display only one image in one window at time. So you probably will have to merge those images manually and display the result.

Comment: I solved it... there is no need to load a seperate alpha layer... the portion of image which you want to remove, color it black... read it asusual with opencv functions... use alpha blend as following 

cvAddWeighted(&sourceFrame,alpha,yourImage,beta,gamma,&DestinationFrame);

alpha = 1 beta = 1 and gamma = 0

black colored part of yourimage would be removed and the rest of the image is alphablended to sourceimage and placed to destination image...

Comment: this last comment should be the answer!

Comment: You should select the background color carefully, when using this method. Using blue (r=0, g=0, b=255) is common because of its absence in human skin (photos of people etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can use cv::imread() with IMREAD_UNCHANGED option, to read the data to a cv::Mat structure. If you still need an IplImage to work with, it is possible to convert from cv::Mat to IplImage without losing the alpha channel.