# Which is the most efficient way to do alpha mask in opencv?

Tags: performance, optimization, opencv

I know OpenCV only supports binary masks.
But I need to do an overlay where I have a grayscale mask that specifies transparency of the overlay.

Eg. if a pixel in the mask is 50% white it should mean a `cv::addWeighted` operation for that pixel with alpha=beta=0.5, gamma = 0.0.

Now, if there is no opencv library function, what algorithm would you suggest as the most efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did something like this for a fix.

```
typedef double Mask_value_t;
typedef Mat_<Mask_value_t> Mask;
void cv::addMasked(const Mat& src1, const Mat& src2, const Mask& mask, Mat& dst)
{
  MatConstIterator_<Vec3b> it1 = src1.begin<Vec3b>(), it1_end = src1.end<Vec3b>(); 
  MatConstIterator_<Vec3b> it2 = src2.begin<Vec3b>();
  MatConstIterator_<Mask_value_t> mask_it = mask.begin();
  MatIterator_<Vec3b> dst_it = dst.begin<Vec3b>();

  for(; it1 != it1_end; ++it1, ++it2, ++mask_it, ++dst_it)
    *dst_it = (*it1) * (1.0-*mask_it) + (*it2) * (*mask_it);
}
```

I have not optimized nor made safe this code yet with assertions.
Working assumptions: all Mat's and the Mask are the same size and Mat's are normal three channel color images.

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar problem, where I wanted to apply a png with transparency.
My solution was using Mat expressions:

```
void AlphaBlend(const Mat& imgFore, Mat& imgDst, const Mat& alpha)
{
    vector<Mat> vAlpha;
    Mat imgAlpha3;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) vAlpha.push_back(alpha);
    merge(vAlpha,imgAlpha3)

    Mat blend = imgFore.mul(imgAlpha3,1.0/255) +
                imgDst.mul(Scalar::all(255)-imgAlpha3,1.0/255);
    blend.copyTo(imgDst);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

OpenCV supports RGBA images which you can create by using [`mixchannels`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=rgba#mixchannels) or the `split` and `merge` functions to combine your images with your greyscale mask. I hope this is what you are looking for!

Using this method you can combine your grayscale mask with your image like so:

```
    cv::Mat gray_image, mask, rgba_image;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> result;
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(image_path);
    cv::split(image, result);
    cv::cvtColor(image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::threshold(gray_image, mask, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    result.push_back(mask);
    cv::merge(result, rgba_image);
    imwrite("rgba.png", rgba_image);
```

Keep in mind that you cannot view RGBA images using `cv::imshow` as described in [read-rgba-image-opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667929/read-rgba-image-opencv) and you cannot save your image as jpeg since that format does not support transparency. It seems that you can combine channels using `cv::cvtcolor` as shown in [opencv-2-3-convert-mat-to-rgba-pixel-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265125/opencv-2-3-convert-mat-to-rgba-pixel-array)

Comment: Thanks, but what happens if I put an RGBA picture over the top of an other? Does it adjust the transparency of the upper-one according to the Alpha channel?

Comment: I have not tried combining two rgba images using something like cv::addWeighted but I imagine that it would work according to the equation: dst = saturate(src1*alpha + src2*beta + gamma).